# C# WinForms key-up event is confusing when two child form are opened in MDIForm

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I am working on C# WinForms 4.5 .NET Framework. I am using key-up events for the keyboard Up and Down keys. When only one child form is open in MDIForm then it's working perfectly, but when there are multiple open child forms it loses its focus and the event is not working.

I tried focussing the form and trued the down or up key, but then it lost the focus and changed the focus to other form.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to stop particular KeyEvent by override ProcessCmdKey method

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if ((keyData == Keys.Right) || (keyData == Keys.Left) ||
            (keyData == Keys.Up) || (keyData == Keys.Down))
        {
            //Do custom stuff or nothing.
            //true if key was processed by control, false otherwise
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
    }
```